# HTML Content in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization, uitextview

I have html string which is loading in a UITextView as NSAttributedString. Following delegate method of UITextView is not calling when contents are in Arabic, but its calling when contents are in english

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange;
```

I noticed that href links are clickable in english and not clickable in arabic.

I use following code to convert NSAttributedString.

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                            initWithData: [contentWithStyle dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                                            options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
                                            documentAttributes: nil
                                            error: nil
                                            ];
```

Comment: can you share with us the Arabic HTML ?

Comment: @AymanIbrahim sure

Comment: @AymanIbrahim

<html dir=\"rtl\"><style>hr{display:none;}h4{color:#002d72;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;}p{font-size:15px;color:#002d72;font-family:NexaRegular;text-align:justify;}body{font-size:15px;color:#002d72;font-family:NexaRegular;text-align:justify;}</style><body><p>​المضاربة;<a href=\"https://google.co.in\">إضغط هنا</a>​​</p></body></html>

Comment: I got this content from api call. When i replace content with google translated arabic text its working :(

Comment: I noticed that you are writing google URL incorrectly,
Use this:
<html dir=\"rtl\"><style>hr{display:none;}h4{color:#002d72;font-fa‌​mily:Arial;font-size‌​:15px;}p{font-size:1‌​5px;color:#002d72;fo‌​nt-family:NexaRegula‌​r;text-align:justify‌​;}body{font-size:15p‌​x;color:#002d72;font‌​-family:NexaRegular;‌​text-align:justify;}‌​</style><body><p>​مح‌​توى الاختبار الخاص بي;<a href=\"https://www.google.com/\">إضغط هنا</a>​​</p></body></html>

Accept the answer if it worked with you.

Comment: @AymanIbrahim no, google url is correct its used in Indian region

Comment: navigate to it in the browser and copy paste it into the HTML.

Comment: yeah the url is working

Comment: Use the code in the answer, to print any parsing errors if exists.

Comment: Its working and no error occurred

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156521/discussion-between-ayman-ibrahim-and-user6788419).

Comment: @user6788419 Did you set the textview isEditable property to NO?

Comment: @DipankarDas Yes. Its working fine for English but not working for Arabic

Comment: @user6788419 But i checked with your code. shouldInteractWithURL is called for both type of text on my machine.

Comment: See the 4th comment @DipankarDas

Comment: @user6788419 I used the htmlString from your 3rd comment.

Comment: @DipankarDas Something is happening while copy text from outside Xcode. Its not working with api contents only. Now i am thinking that is there any encoding using in backend

Comment: @user6788419 Maybe your data is not valid UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @DipankarDas U may be correct

Answer (score 0):

Use this to read the HTML:

```
[self. textView setEditable:NO];
NSError *error = nil;
NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[HTML dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:@(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:nil error:&error];
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %s %i", error.localizedDescription, __func__, __LINE__);
}
else
{
    self. textView.text = @"";
    [self. textView.textStorage appendAttributedString:attString];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *htmlString = @"yourHtmlString";

htmlString = [htmlString stringByAppendingString:@"<style>body{font-family:'yourFont'; font-size:'size';}</style>"];


NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                              initWithData: [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                                   options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
                        documentAttributes: nil
                                     error: nil
                    ];


yourTextView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Updated:

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<html dir=\"rtl\"><style>hr{display:none;}h4{color:#002d72;font-fa‌ mily:Arial;font-size‌ :15px;}p{font-size:1‌ 5px;color:#002d72;fo‌ nt-family:NexaRegula‌ r;text-align:justify‌ ;}body{font-size:15p‌ x;color:#002d72;font‌ -family:NexaRegular;‌ text-align:justify;}‌ </style><body><p> ال‌ مضاربة;<a href=\"google.co.in\">إضغط هنا</a> </p></body></html>";

    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                            initWithData: [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                                            options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
                                            documentAttributes: nil
                                            error: nil
                                            ];

    textView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

[image]

Comment: I have added the updated answer which shows your arabic string on UITextView.

Comment: is it clickable?

Comment: No its not..sorry

Comment: thats my problem